# how to minimize the speed of brushless motor

Tags: performance, controls, robotics

I have a RC car with motor 25 kv , I wanted to minimize the motor speed from 55 miles /s to 1 m/s speed and to add encoder to it to make auonomouse a specific purpose in robotics application
if someone have idea about the components required and the steps required

Comment: It looks like your question is not about programing and thus it is off-topic on stack-overflow. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ might be a better fit. I advise you to check the other Stack Exchange websites.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.